# timeseries anomaly detection: one model per series or group of series or a single big model to rule them all?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, model, anomaly-detection

Context:

I have thousands of IoT device time series. Multiple metrics are tracked per time period. In order to perform predictive maintenance, I need to detect anomalies.

Problem:

There are multiple categories of devices or devices from the same category with different firmware versions.
I wonder if I should train one model per:

- time-series (find anomalies per device)
- group of time-series (figure out if one device behaves differently from its cohort)
- one single big model to rule them all (is there a strange cohort/category of devices)

Or maybe even a combination of all of the above?

I am particularly interested to get this question answered for models like https://matrixprofile.org/ or an autoencoder based approach.

Comment: What kind of anomalies are you looking for / do you have? Is it on device characteristics, like firmware issues, network issues etc - or on the machine/setting that the devices observe? The latter is typically more the case for predictive maintenance

Comment: If it is the latter (machine/environment) that is important, then it the characteristics of the machines/env that primarily should be considered when choosing approach. And hopefully device characteristics like firmware version can be ignored, or controlled for

Comment: Probably more with regards to the quality of network connectivity.